# ¿Pasa algo por copiar la respuesta de alguien cambiando dos cosas y publicándola?

Tags: soporte

Me pregunto qué pasa si alguien responde a una pregunta. Llega otro que tiene más puntuación, te copia la respuesta y le cambia un par de cosas.

Como la otra persona tiene mas reputación, casi seguro que se lleva el mérito, cuando tu lo has respondido antes. ¿Esto tiene consecuencias?

Answer (score 15):

> ¿Esto tiene consecuencias?

**Sí.**

Si te encuentras un caso de este estilo, utiliza el caso "custom" de reportes para moderador y explica la situación. Se va a analizar y si es cierto lo que comentas (una copia **95-100% exacta** o lo suficiente para que se vea claro el **plagio**) se va a eliminar esa respuesta y dependiendo de la gravedad puede tener otras consecuencias.

> Como la otra persona tiene mas reputación, casi seguro que se lleva el mérito, cuando tu lo has respondido antes.

Esto no creo que sea así. Por mi experiencia personal en la comunidad, aunque un usuario de más reputación responda, si alguien contesta *antes* de manera correcta normalmente esa es la respuesta más votada y/o aceptada. En cualquier caso no es algo por lo que preocuparse.

Comment: No sabía que se podía reportar una respuesta por ser plagio de otra. Muchas gracias por la info :)

Comment: Creo que no sería común alguien que tiene más reputación plagie una respuesta, **si es así habría que reportarlo**. Hey @MiquelColl espero no aplique el auto-plagio, si es así creo que estoy en problemas ಠ_ಠ hehe.

Comment: Como bien dice @Elenasys no es algo común. Y el auto plagio no es plagio hehe. Es válido trasladar información del sitio en inglés a aquí aunque es importante recordar que añadir un link a la respuesta original siempre da más calidad a la respuesta :)

Comment: A veces ocurre también que dos personas tienen ideas similares para responder, es normal, no todo hay que tomarlo como un plagio. Si bien es cierto que normalmente X personas producen X soluciones diferentes, también hay problemas o situaciones que tienen una manera más o menos estándar de resolverse a la que muchos estamos acostumbrados y eso se va a reflejar en las respuestas.

Comment: He eliminado varios comentarios ya que el tema se ha desviado de lo preguntado en general por algo muy específico. Como comento en mi respuesta, si se tienen sospechas claras de plagio lo mejor es reportar y ya lo miraremos. Más allá de eso tened en cuenta que según el tipo de preguntas las respuestas pueden ser muy parecidos y eso no constituye plagio.

Comment: @MiquelColl Supongamos que la respuesta copiada cita al autor original como exige la licencia cc by-sa 3.0 bajo la que todas las respuestas y preguntas de SO están disponibles. En ese caso no se puede reportar por plagio pues no hay plagio sino una copia autorizada. ¿Es posible reportar esa pregunta copiada por "No aportar nada nuevo con respecto a una respuesta ya publicada"?

Comment: Sugiero agrgar los enlaces a [¿Cómo referir material a otros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) y [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/289691)