# Un usuario está copiando respuestas

Tags: discusión, respuesta, moderación

Acabo de ver varias preguntas seguidas con actividad de un mismo usuario. Para mí sorpresa, respondió cada una copiando una de las otras respuestas.

Revisé todas sus respuestas hasta el momento y ninguna es original. Todas son un copia-pega completo o parcial de otra respuesta ya dada. A veces se toma la molestia de darle formato y a veces no.

Yo creo que deberíamos hacer algo porque no está aportando nada.

Aprovecho para preguntar, qué deberíamos hacer la próxima vez que veamos algo así? ¿Reportar sus preguntas? ¿Hacer una publicación en meta? ¿Comentarlo en el chat?

Comment: Se reportan como duplicados y si el usuario es culpable se lo suspende por plagio... voy a chequear...

Comment: @gbianchi y cómo hago eso? Elijo **se requiere atención del moderador** y escribo **duplicado**?

Comment: claro.. si nos avisas asi se puede... en este caso, ya revise todo y me ocupe...

Comment: No se deben usar Meta para hacer acusaciones de usuarios específicos. Si existe un problema con un usuario específico reportalo a los moderadores, para ello basta con reportar una de las respuestas para atención de los moderadores. Por otro lado, Meta si se puede usar para preguntar que hacer ante una situación, pero primero lee la [help] y busca si existen preguntas relacionadas con tu consulta. Referencia [¿Qué hago si veo a alguien haciendo algo malo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

Comment: Relacionado [¿Pasa algo por copiar la respuesta de alguien cambiando dos cosas y publicándola?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1162/65)

Comment: @Rubén ví la primera pero creí que no es duplicado porque habla de una situación diferente. Aunque la segunda publicación que compartiste sí se asemeja a lo que planteo.

Comment: Gracias por responder Mateo. El modelo de preguntas y respuestas del sitio tiene la intención de que quien pregunta mencione las preguntas similares que haya revisado indicando brevemente porque no responden a esta nueva pregunta. Es válido que se cierre una pregunta como duplicado de una pregunta que no sea exactamente igual si la respuesta funciona para la nueva pregunta. Según entiendo no hay "penalización" (baneo de preguntas) para quien el autor de preguntas cerradas como duplicadas ya que las preguntas cerradas como duplicado sirven para localizar las respuestas.

Comment: haaa tenia rato que no veia una pregunta en meta cerrada por duplicada XD